# Small Baseball Scoreboard using 2 to 3 breadboards

Tags: power, led, spi, switch, project

I'm helping my son start an Arduino small baseball scoreboard (roughly 2 or 3 breadboards in size). Im thinking to use qty 2, 2 digit 7 segment LED's (score of each team), an LCD 1602 module (inning tracker), using a serial monitor. Last is 3 individual LED's (controlled with a switch or remote).

My question is: can one arduino drive all of this? What would be a recommended configuration?
Thank you,Dave

Comment: which arduino? there's many models to choose from

Comment: Codewise that shouldn’t be a problem. But you might run out of pins to connect them. I’d suggest getting the seven segment displays on a breakout with a driver chip on it. Those will make them easier to use, and require less pins.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can very easily verify this yourself:

1. Per item (1602LCD, 7 segment LCD and LEDs check how many pins you need and what type, like e.g. I2C or SPI for the 1602 LCD). The 7 segment displays can have many or less pins, depending on the 'controller', See the reaction of CrossRoads below.
2. Count them together. If it fits on the Arduino you want to use OK. The Uno is cheapest, so if it fits on it, you use that, otherwise you can go to the Mega.
3. As alternative, and you need 'generic pins, called GPIOs' (not SPI/I2C) for some, you can use multiplexers like 74HC595 to reduce the number of GPIOs needed, at the cost of some speed (not critical for your project), and some more programming work.
4. In some cases you can use a MAX7219 driver IC, see (again) the remark of Crossroads below.

Comment: Do the 2-digit displays have seperate pins for all the segments? The parts witll have 16 or 18 pins. If they have common segment pins, the parts will have 10 pins; 1 for each segment, and a common anode or common cathode for each digit. The 2nd type will need multiplexing: display data for 1 digit for a short time (like 3-5 milliseconds) with one anode/cathode pin, then display data for the 2nd digit with the other anode/cathode pin.  If the 2 displays are the same, then both units can have their segment pins in parallel, and 4 unique common anode/cathode pins are used to multiplex the digits.

Comment: @CrossRoads Thanks for the valuable remark, I refered to your remark in my answer.

Comment: If the 7-segment displays are common cathode, you can easily use a MAX7219 to drive them, just write the data to be displayed to 4 registers and it takes care of the multiplexing.  Common anode is also possible,  but you have to do a little data mapping.

Comment: @CrossRoads thanks for improving my answer again (updated the answer).